# Apache Beam Python 3.x method scope

Tags: python, python-3.6, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Just migrated my Pipeline from Python 2.7 to 3.6 and Apache Beam 2.17. (Same happens with Apache Beam 2.16)

Would like to understand better Python 3.x method scope in DataFlow/Apache Beam.

Code [here](https://pastebin.com/fgjV4dZv):

When calling `beam.FlatMap` inside `main` method:

```
# Window them, and batch them into batches of 50
    output_tweets = (lines
                     | 'assign window key' >> beam.WindowInto(
            window.FixedWindows(10))
                     | 'batch into n batches' >> BatchElements(
            min_batch_size=99, max_batch_size=100)
                     | 'predict sentiment' >> beam.FlatMap(
            lambda messages: prediction_handler(messages))
                     )
```

In Python 2.x my function `prediction_handler` was defined before this part of code and worked just fine, now I'm getting:

```
INFO:root:2020-01-11T07:55:54.790Z: JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error received from SDK harness for instruction -229: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 780, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 441, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "twitter_dataflow.py", line 210, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'prediction_handler' is not defined
```

If I create a function "main" and define all functions inside this one, this seems to work, is this expected behavior?
The same happens for any method even if they are declared before, and as workaround I needed to move all functions inside `main`:

- initialize_api
- aggregate_format
- predict
- prediction_handler

Functions were defined before. Already looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947140/nameerror-name-one-is-not-defined-python-3-4-error) question.

Comment: I don't think that should be expected if I understand it correctly. I can run a simple pipeline such as [this](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/17f1ce31e9960e5482dfd3502d762cb2) with both direct and Dataflow runners (same Python and SDK versions). If it happens locally you can try to simplify the code, debug it and inspect the namespace, etc

Comment: Since it reads from PubSub, pipeline doesn't let me run locally, will try to simplify it to troubleshoot it, thanks for the response.

Comment: Ok, let me know. By the way, you can test pipelines with `ReadFromPubSub` locally if you use the `--streaming` flag

Comment: Have you checked whether the code posted by @GuillemXercavins works for you? Also, could you please provide an example of a code that does not work?

Comment: @DanielDuato the example that doesnt work is attached to original post. I will give it a try to Guillem code and update

Comment: I was asking for an example of code with the functions outside of `main` (the one you linked has the functions inside `main`), in order to reproduce your use case and make it as similar as possible to the situation in which the error appeared.